# Why wake up writer when pipe is full?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, drivers

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/fs/pipe.c#L247

When a pipe was full, shouldn't it wake up the reader to read out data?

```
    /*
     * We only wake up writers if the pipe was full when we started
     * reading in order to avoid unnecessary wakeups.
     *
     * But when we do wake up writers, we do so using a sync wakeup
     * (WF_SYNC), because we want them to get going and generate more
     * data for us.
     */
    was_full = pipe_full(pipe->head, pipe->tail, pipe->max_usage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs when the pipe is read; since the pipe is being read, it’s not going to be full after the read completes, so there will be room for more writes.

If the pipe was full before the start of the read, that implies that there may be writers blocked because of the pipe being full; those writers are useful to wake up now to minimise the wait time. If the pipe wasn’t full, then any blocked writers aren’t blocked because of a full pipe, so freeing room up in the pipe isn’t going to help them and waking them up isn’t useful.

Readers are woken up [when the pipe is written to](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/fs/pipe.c#L562).